# Advice requested for uploading metadata in bulk to a Sharepoint Online document library (including managed metadata fields)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, managed-metadata, metadata

I have a 4000+ item Sharepoint Online document library, and an excel sheet containing associated metadata. Some of the columns have multiple entries per field, and I would like to use Managed Metadata term sets for those columns (so that I can set up filters later). The solution presented in another thread here does not work, because it is not possible to paste data into Managed Metadata fields using the Quick Edit feature. Is there any way to use excel or csv to upload the metadata, and map the associated data to the term set terms? Even if I end up not using the managed metadata, is there a straightforward way to upload bulk metadata from csv (or by any other method) to a Sharepoint Online document library, other than Quick Edit?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it is possible to upload column metadata to a document library via Excel spreadsheet, neither managed metadata column values nor other types of column values.

There are several third-party tools that provide bulk-tag or bulk-edit functions, which might do some help. Please see the links below.

References:

[HOW TO BULK-TAG A SHAREPOINT LIBRARY TO ASSIGN MANAGED METADATA TO ALL DOCUMENTS AUTOMATICALLY?](https://www.layer2solutions.com/support/knowledge-management-suite-faqs/sharepoint-managed-metadata-bulk-tagging)

[Bulk Edit SharePoint Metadata: The Basics.](https://sharegate.com/blog/bulk-editing-and-tagging-sharepoint-metadata-101)

[Data / Document Importer For SharePoint.](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=difs)

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to import a spreadsheet to SharePoint (including SharePoint Online) to create a list with basic metadata columns. Here is Microsoft's article on how to do it. I performed the steps in SharePoint Online and it worked. I doubt this can be used for Managed Metadata, however.

[Create a List Based on a Spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa)